# linux Using system("ping") blocked in daemon process

Tags: c, linux, daemon, ping

In my daemon process,I try to use ping to detect host is alive.

code:

```
sprintf(pingCmd,"ping -c1 -t%d %s",time,ip);
if (system(pingCmd)) {
    //fail
}
else {
    //success
}
```

but when I remove the destination host network cable.

My daemon process will blocking at system()

```
#0  0x00007f75362fbc7d in waitpid () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f7536281f5e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f7536282370 in system () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

so  I write anthor program, not a daemon

the code not be blocking at sysem(),

even i remove the destionation host network cable,

how to using system("ping") at daemon process

Comment: `system` is always blocking

Comment: `and (system()) returns after the command has been completed` http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: What's the point of the ping?  If it's to check if the host is alive before you do something that contacts the host, it's useless.

Comment: what do you mean with *alive*? alive means all services working? then don't use ping.  ping is a *wait for no living host* service, badly implemented on a server that cannot wait for a host to respond it's not alive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ping command is blocking.  Try the exact same ping command from the command-line to see the result.

By the way, I highly recommend implementing the ping itself inside the daemon - you'll run into far fewer problems.  Running a command through the system() function introduces a lot of complexity that can confuse and cause incorrect results.

With that said, to get this working, find the right ping command, with the correct arguments, to do the job, by testing from the command-line.  Make sure to check for timeouts as well.

Comment: I highly recommend not bothering to ping the host and just try using it as intended.  A host that doesn't respond to a ping might very well still be fine, and even if it does respond to the ping it might not respond to an SSH attempt, for example.  The ping is worthless.

Comment: For the most part, I tend to agree with you Andrew.  However, this is the Ops question, and there are valid reasons to ping a host.  For example, perhaps he's writing a monitoring tool that will alert when a host appears to be unreachable.  Certainly, I wouldn't 2-step a normal connection with such a ping check.

Comment: by the way, implementing ping requires packet(sometimes called raw) sockets and that's a *only for root eyes* thing...  complicated matter.  Using ping visibility of hosts implies normally having a parallel process doing the pings and caching the results, so the actual server doesn't lose time waiting for a reply (it only guesses from cached last reply, stored somewhere)

Comment: I am having the same issue as OP. My ping command works from the CLI and when I run the program non daemon. But does not work when the program is run daemonized